# Local dygraph application

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I know this question has been **asked** before, but I do not find any satisfactory **answers** out there. When using dygraph to display local CSV files, modern browsers such as Chrome throw a security exception (which does or does not make sense whatever way you look at it)

People came up with solutions such as using the --allow-files-from-files option, or using different browsers such as firefox. Firefox however has similar issues unless you put the CSV file in the same folder as the html that contains the dygraph object. This is far from optimal too!

Im very hungry for a good and common way to fix this, so that the webapplication actually works for multiple browsers, without disrupting my file hierarchy. Since I do not think this is out there, I'm hoping the developer(s?) of dygraph can come up with some alternative way of parsing the CSV data, since this is beyond the scope I can go.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Just start a web server in the directory you want to access. You can use the Python simplehttpserver:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

or node's http-server

```
npm install -g http-server
http-server
```

Then you're in the better-defined world of `http://`, not `file://`.

Comment: Sorry, but its a fully automated program, so running webservers just won't cut it. I sometimes run many (>10) simulations on one machine, and I do not wish to run a webserver for every one of those.

Comment: You only need to run one server for your whole file system, not one per file.